# How Do You Enable SAML IdP in a Partner Community?

Tags: single-sign-on, connected-apps, saml, partner-communities

I am helping a client that needs to connect their partner portal, a Salesforce Partner Community.  They need to setup an SSO for their partners from the partner portal into another web application using SAML.  We are familiar with enabling Salesforce as an IdP for internal users, but not for partners.  Can someone tell us how to setup and configure a Salesforce Partner Community as a SAML IdP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The process is very much similar to how you set up for Internal Users except that you need to replace with Community URLS .

Lets look at step by step the mechanism to accomplish the same .For simplicity I am taking another winter 17 pre release org as a SP (Service Provider)

**Step 1**

Set Up a Partner Community in Salesforce(This is your IDP org) .Not going to detail this but should be straight forward

**Step 2**

Download the Self Signed Certificate from your IDP org .Your IDP org is where you have set up partner community .Navigate to

> Setup | Security Controls | Identity Provider

Click on Download Certificate button

You will clearly see for your Partner Community there will be Discovery EndPoint URL .Carefully Note this down as this will be needed by your Service Provider .Also note down the issuer

[image]

**Step 3**

Lets go to the service provider screen .In my example its another salesforce Instance (Winter 17 pre release org ).

> Set up | Security Control | Single Sign On Settings

[image]

Carefully note two things

1.The issuer was obtained from IDP .

2.The IDP login URL is of one we noted in step 2 from IDP

3.We have uploaded the certificate which we downloaded in previous step

**Step 4**

Create a Connected App in IDP and allow the partner community profile for the connected app

[image]

Carefully note that I have configured ACS URL which was  provided by the service provider in previous step

Once your connected app is save and when you click on Detail link of the  the Connected App ,for every community you will get an IDP intitated URL

[image]

The IDP initiated login URL is what you need to put on a tab or visualforce .You will then see that User is redirected to the SP once user clicks on the IDP initiated URL without having to log into the SP org .

Comment: wow!  thank you so much for the answer and the step by step details.  you should publish this.

Comment: Good one Mohith.

Comment: Irony is good answers do not get much attention :) .